# Kafka consumer group does not have an id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-cloud

In a kafka cluster running on confluent cloud I have a number of consumers. When I make a GET request to `{confluentUrl}/kafka/v3/clusters/{cluster_id}/consumer-groups`, one of the consumer groups has the following properties:

```
"consumer_group_id": "",
"is_simple": true,
"partition_assignor": "",
"state": "EMPTY",
```

Everything in the cluster appears to be functioning fine, but I am concerned about this consumer group. It is subscribed to a topic, and is ~100000 messages behind.

How can something like this happen? Is it possible to delete this consumer group?

Comment: Maybe you have a consumer that assigned manually the partitions instead of using subscribe? I believe in that case there will not be a consumer group id, not sure if it would show in the confluent API though

Comment: are you able to see list of consumer group from confluent cloud UI?  if you go to env -> ${env} ->${cluster}->"Data Integration" -> Clients you can find all live consumer groups.